# Как сделать скролл для виджета со всем его содержимым?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlabel, qscrollarea

Нужно поместить кнопку, которая будет находиться **`справа внизу`** изображения (как в `Paint`, для растяжения изображения), при этом чтобы можно использовать скролл и кнопка была видна.

Необязательно чтобы кнопка двигалась достаточно, чтобы скролл не перекрывал её.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.pixmap = QPixmap("hold.png")
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        lbl = QLabel('text', self)
        lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        lbl.setGeometry(0, 0, 280, 280)
        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')


class ScrollOnExample(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.widget = Example()
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark)
        scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(scroll)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ScrollOnExample()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Та кнопка, что вы описали похоже на QSizeGrip: http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsizegrip.html

Comment: #gil9red она не должна менять размер окна, даже пусть не двигается. Она должна быть на границе изображения, при этом я мог задать её размеры и скролл не перекрывал её

Comment: А зачем? Можно попробовать разместить layout и на него ту кнопку, но не уверен что с QScrollArea это выйдет. Либо можно вручную кнопку перемещать, для этого понадобится или наследник от QScrollArea, у которого mouseMoveEvent будет перекрыт, либо понадобится event-filter

Answer (score 1):

я увидел вашу задачу так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap("im.png").scaled(60, 60))
        self._update() 
        
    def _update(self):
        w = self.window().w - 120 + self.window().deltaHorizontal if self.window().w <= 710 else 590
        h = self.window().h - 120 + self.window().deltaVertical if self.window().h <= 674 else 554
        self.move(w, h)
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel:hover {border-radius: 4px; border: 2px solid #0ff;}")
        self.clicked.emit()
        super(Label, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel:hover {border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid #f00;}")
        super(Label, self).enterEvent(event)
        
    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel {border: none;}")
        super(Label, self).leaveEvent(event)
        

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()
        self.lbl1 = Label(self.lbl)    
        self.lbl1.show()

    def initUI(self):
        self.pixmap = QPixmap("im.png")
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.lbl = QLabel('text', self)
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.lbl.setGeometry(0, 0, 280, 280)
        hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')


class ScrollArea(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScrollArea, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Подключите события прокрутки
        self.verticalScrollBar().actionTriggered.connect(self.onActionTriggered)
        self.horizontalScrollBar().actionTriggered.connect(self.onActionTriggered)

    def onActionTriggered(self, action=7):
        self.window().deltaVertical = self.verticalScrollBar().sliderPosition()
        if self.verticalScrollBar().sliderPosition() == self.verticalScrollBar().maximum():
            self.window().deltaVertical -= 10
        self.window().deltaHorizontal = self.horizontalScrollBar().sliderPosition()
        if self.horizontalScrollBar().sliderPosition() == self.horizontalScrollBar().maximum():
            self.window().deltaHorizontal -= 10
        self.window().widget.lbl1._update()


class ScrollOnExample(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.w = 495
        self.h = 340
        self.deltaVertical = 0
        self.deltaHorizontal = 0
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.scroll = ScrollArea(self)          
        self.widget = Example(self)            
        self.widget.lbl1.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.scroll.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.scroll)
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        delta = 0 if self.scroll.contentsRect().width() <= 695 else 20
        self.w = self.width()
        self.h = self.height() + delta 
        self.scroll.onActionTriggered()        

    def onClicked(self):
        print(f'*** onClicked: Делайте что-нибудь! ***')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ScrollOnExample()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**im.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Daniil я попробовал ответить на ваш спящий вопрос. Проверьте.

Comment: @Daniil что не так?